# Valid way to check that a double has been assigned a value of 0.0

Tags: c++, floating-point, double

I know there are plenty of pitfalls with using the equal comparator with `double`'s so I'm cautious on how to implement a check for a value equal to *exactly* `0.0`.  Basically, I want to know if a value was never assigned or if it was intentionally assigned the value `0.0` with a literal.  I do not want to know if it is *nearly* zero (ex - `0.0000000001`).

So I'm debating between using `val == 0.0` or something like so:

```
bool isZero(double val)
{
    if (val > std::numeric_limits<double>::min()) {
        return false;
    } else if (val < -std::numeric_limits<double>::min()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Would there be any difference between these two statements?  Should I favor one over the other?  I'm particularly concerned with the underflow scenario where `val == -0.0`.

Thanks

---

I should have clarified the 'never assigned' statement to 'never assigned after default initialization'.

Comment: 1) Consider also `std::fpclassify(val) == FP_ZERO`. 2) Be careful with NaNs. Your `isZero` returns `true` for a NaN.

Comment: Also take care about the "never assigned" thing... Uninitialized local variables will have *indeterminate* values, and using such values (in *any* way) leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: Why are you concerned about `-0.0`? It's a valid zero, just like `0.0`. It's not only a result of underflow, e.g. `-1.0*0.0 == -0.0`.

Comment: There is no way to tell whether a `double` was initialized or not, and there is no way to tell whether an initializer was a literal or some other expression.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39108471/is-it-ok-to-compare-floating-points-to-0-0-without-epsilon

Comment: == does exactly what you think it does. The reason people tell you not to use == is because *usually* you *do* want to know if something is nearly zero.

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()` is the smallest normalized number.  You could have subnormal numbers (also called denormalized) that are not 0 but are smaller than `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to know if a floating point variable is exactly `0.0` or `-0.0` then there is nothing wrong with using `val == 0.0`.

If you need to know if it is exactly `0.0` and not `-0.0` then you must verify that you are using ieee-754 floating points and check whether the bit representation is all zero.

Comment: You could also use `val == 0.0 && signbit(val) == 0` for the second case.

Comment: You could add that initializing `val` to `NAN` would allow later determining if it had been deliberately set to zero.